# Filtrando dados a partir de um vetor

Tags: r

Eu tenho um data frame que lista uma série de avaliações de clientes para diferentes produtos (cada registro é uma avaliação/nota). Eu preciso fazer alguns boxplots com as avaliações de alguns produtos específicos (os ids desses produtos estão em um vetor), mas não de todos os produtos. Eu gostaria de saber como eu digo em R: Pegue apenas as avaliações dos produtos tem os ids nesse vetor e monte um boxplot para cada produto.
Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sei que a pergunta já esta resolvida mas, pelo que entendi, você precisava retirar alguns produtos da sua base, antes de fazer o boxplot. E o id desses produtos estava salvo em um outro vetor. Por isso segue um pequeno complemento.

Exemplo:

```
excluir_produtos <- c(1,2,3)
base <- data.frame(
  produto = rep(1:5, each = 20),
  nota = runif(100)
)
base <- base[!base$produto %in% excluir_produtos,]
```

Dessa forma, você exclui da base todas as linhas dos produtos 1, 2 e 3.
Em seguida você poderia fazer o gráfico, tanto do jeito que o @Marcus postou como usando o próprio `boxplot`.

```
boxplot(nota ~ produto, base)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de fazer isto é com o pacote `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + geom_boxplot() +
labs(x="Cilindros", y="Milhas por Galão")
```

[image: Boxplot]

Para que isto seja feito, é necessário, em primeiro lugar, juntar o vetor com os IDs dos produtos e o data frame com as avaliações dos clientes.